# jquery couldn't access property inside of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

```
function foo(){
    var a = 1;
    this.b = 2;

    this.c = function(){
        alert(a);
        alert(this.b);

        $('.ei').each(function(){
            alert(a);
            alert(this.b);//undefined <-- i need this to be update to 3
        });
    }

}

var obj = new foo;
obj.b = 3; //update this property before call method
obj.c();
```

I have a method contain jquery each(), and I try to access this object's property, but i get undefined

I will need this property able to update

anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: `this` inside `each` will refer to the current element in the set. Cache `this` to `that` and use `that.b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind this to function.

```
this.c = function(){
    alert(a);
    alert(this.b);

    $('.ei').each(function(){
        alert(a);
        alert(this.b);//undefined <-- i need this to be update to 3
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: i just try, its not working, and u miss " ) " at the end of each();

Comment: yea, you need .bind(this) to function assigned to this.c, and it should work. I edited post, please check it now.

Comment: If you have the variable you require in your lexical scope there's really _no need to use `.bind`_ - it's less efficient than just aliasing a copy yourself

Comment: The `.bind` on the outer `this.c` is also completely unnecessary